# Split the paragraphs based on a number of words(150 words more or less)

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I have a lot of large text in my WordPress ready to be edited. But they are long paragraphs and I would like to be able to split paragraphs into 150 words per paragraph. Would be better to read.

Is there a Code Snip or Plugin I can use to do that?
Can someone show me some PHP code to do that?

For example:

```
High-powered model rockets are a fun and exciting hobby for people of all ages. Before you can launch a model rocket, however, it is important to prepare properly in order to ensure a safe and successful launch. This article will provide an overview of the steps you should take before launching a model rocket.  First, you should read the instructions for the rocket carefully. Make sure you understand the parts of the rocket and how they fit together. You may also want to review any safety instructions provided with the rocket. Next, you should assemble the rocket according to the instructions. If any parts are damaged or missing, replace them before attempting to launch. It is also important to make sure that the rocket is securely and properly connected to the launch pad. Once the rocket is assembled, you should make sure that the launch area is clear of people, animals, and other objects. Then, attach the launch controller to the launch pad and connect the igniter wires to the motor. Finally, make sure to connect the launch controller to an approved power source. At this point, you are ready to launch the rocket. Before doing so, however, it is important to check the local weather conditions. You should also check with any local authorities to make sure that model rocket launches are permitted in your area. Finally, you should always have an adult present when launching a model rocket. This will help ensure the safety of everyone involved. Following these steps will help you prepare for a successful model rocket launch. Have fun and be safe!
```

would become

```
High powered model rockets are a fun and exciting hobby for people of all ages. Before you can launch a model rocket, however, it is important to prepare properly in order to ensure a safe and successful launch. This article will provide an overview of the steps you should take before launching a model rocket.  First, you should read the instructions for the rocket carefully. 

Make sure you understand the parts of the rocket and how they fit together. You may also want to review any safety instructions provided with the rocket. Next, you should assemble the rocket according to the instructions. If any parts are damaged or missing, replace them before attempting to launch. 

It is also important to make sure that the rocket is securely and properly connected to the launch pad. Once the rocket is assembled, you should make sure that the launch area is clear of people, animals, and other objects. Then, attach the launch controller to the launch pad and connect the igniter wires to the motor. 

Finally, make sure to connect the launch controller to an approved power source. At this point, you are ready to launch the rocket. Before doing so, however, it is important to check the local weather conditions. 

You should also check with any local authorities to make sure that model rocket launches are permitted in your area. Finally, you should always have an adult present when launching a model rocket. This will help ensure the safety of everyone involved. Following these steps will help you prepare for a successful model rocket launch. Have fun and be safe!
```

What I have done

I tried looking for a plugin or PHP code example to use in my WordPress but did not find any that worked.

Here is What I found in PHP that was Promising but I do not know how to implement it in WordPress.

```
$string = 'Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source.';

$sentences = preg_split('/(?<=[.?!;])\s+(?=\p{Lu})/', $string);
$wordcount = 150;
$ii = 0;
$paragraphs = array();
foreach ( $sentences as $value ) {
    if ( isset($paragraphs[$ii]) ) { $paragraphs[$ii] .= $value; }
    else { $paragraphs[$ii] = $value; }
    if ( $wordcount < str_word_count($paragraphs[$ii]) ) {
        $ii++;
    }
}
print_r($paragraphs);
```

Here is a code example for creating a plugin

````
        <?php
    /**
     * The plugin bootstrap file.
     *
     * Plugin Name:  Gutenberg Button
     * Plugin URI:   https://github.com/davilera/gutenberg-button
     * Description:  Adding a formatting button in Gutenberg.
     * Version:      1.0.0
     *
     * Author:       David Aguilera
     * Author URI:   https://neliosoftware.com
     * License:      GPL-3.0+
     * License URI:  http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.txt
     *
     * Text Domain:  gutenberg-button
     *
     * @author  David Aguilera <david.aguilera@neliosoftware.com>
     */
    
    namespace Gutenberg_Button;
    
    defined( 'ABSPATH' ) or die();
    
    function init_constants() {
      define( 'GUTENBERG_BUTTON_URL', untrailingslashit( plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) ) );
      define( 'GUTENBERG_BUTTON_PATH', untrailingslashit( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) ) );
      define( 'GUTENBERG_BUTTON_VERSION', get_file_data( __FILE__, [ 'Version' ], 'plugin' )[0] );
    }//end init_constants()
    add_action( 'plugins_loaded', __NAMESPACE__ . '\init_constants', 1 );```

How can I get this Code to do its magic on all the text in my editor?
How can I Put a button at the top of my editor to do that when I press it?
How can I get the complete text of the variable into the $str var?
How can I put the result back in the editor?
````

Comment: Your examples are not 150 words, if it was, it would only be broken onto [two lines](https://3v4l.org/jW2AF). Perhaps chunk it at [around 50 words](https://3v4l.org/tguB5) for your expected output.

Answer (score 0):

50 words seems like the optimal solution to chunk to for your expected output. You can utilise the `array_chunk` after splitting words between spaces.

```
$paragraphs = array_map(fn($words): string => implode(' ', $words), array_chunk(explode(' ', $str), 50));
```

After you have these, you can use the `nl2br` to convert the `PHP_EOL` into HTML breaklines.

```
echo nl2br(implode(PHP_EOL, $paragraphs));
```

See it working on [3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/OJUmm) and feel free to alter the word count to achieve the output you want.